How to configure the size of the internal buffer for file IO in PHP?
I want to change the buffer size  for file IO while reading/writing to files from PHP, but the only way to do so is stream_set_write_buffer() which always return -1. I couldn't find any error descriptions with error_reporting(E_ALL); or whatever.
I have a live example that reproduces the problem:
https://onlinephp.io/c/5955f
I am asking for help, why does it fail? How to make it work and what am I missing? No docs helped me so far.

Something like onlinephp.io isn't a good place to test these kind of settings. Did you actually test this on a normal server? OK, I tested it on my server, and indeed it does error out with -1.

yup tested in a bunch of linux-based machines

I did notice this blog that assumes success when the function doesn't return 0 when you look at the code. Also, if you read the User Contributed Notes here (not the official doc!) it sounds like more people are struggling with this. It's mentioned here, but that's 12 years old.

Indeed by looking at the source of PHP this quote seems true: "In the case of plain files, write buffering is supported, but only for stdio files, not plain file descriptors.". If that is how it is now, then writing in php in files can't be named "performant" as one has to maintain "a buffer" in memory (which is a string copied on each concatenation) and then do fwrite and then start over again. Sigh...

Yeah, that seems to be the case. However, it is quite possible that, for local files, the file system (= OS) already does a reasonable job of buffering at a lower level, so not much can be gained if a high-level language like PHP would perform its own buffering.

" the file system (= OS) already does a reasonable job of buffering at a lower level" - I'd want to check that. I used strace to see what syscalls are done with php's "fwrite(...)" and shows simple "write" which is an unbuffered op. Potenially there's no buffering by default at all.

Here is a workaround:
fsync($f);
$err = stream_set_write_buffer($f, 65536);


Why does it fail?
stream_set_write_buffer sets the buffer through setvbuf
if (data->file == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
...
return setvbuf(data->file, NULL, _IOFBF, size);

But PHP's fopen function doesn't call C's fopen function, but instead calls the open system call, which returns a file descriptor, so this file field is a null:
static php_stream *_php_stream_fopen_from_fd_int(...)
{
    ...
    self->file = NULL;
    ...
}

Then I searched this file and found a function called php_stdiop_cast that sets the file field:
data->file = fdopen(data->fd, fixed_mode);

And this function is called by another function called php_stdiop_sync, which is the implementation of fsync and fdatasync functions.

I am marking this as the answer because it gets the job done - we can use the buffer. But the underlying C code is strange :) To prove that I did a script with multiple sequential "fwrite()", strace shows that each statement makes a "write" syscall, so no buffering. When used this "hack" I see that multiple "fwrite"s are merged in a single big "write" syscall, so buffer was enabled.

Based on your sandbox/online environment:
Why stream_set_write_buffer() might fail

Filesystem-specific restrictions: Some filesystems (network drives, configs  of NFS) may restrict or ignore buffer size adjustments.
PHP config or environment: The PHP installation might be running in an environment (containers or read-only modes) that restricts file I/O or buffering settings.
Stream type does NOT support buffering

Stream types and their support



Stream
Supports Buffering?




Regular Files
Yes


php://output
No


php://stdout
No


Network Streams
Depends


Sockets
Depends



